# Sort divs based on values of child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I would like to sort the `.choice_result` divs based on the value of their `.score` child value. So with my js below, the `.choice_result` with a `.score` inside of 100%, should be the first div and not the last. Here's the js:

```
<div class="poll poll_answered">
        <div class="poll_div">
            <h1><strong>Percentages</strong></h1>
            <div class="poll_results" style="display: block;">

            <div class="choice_result" data-choice_percent="0">
                <p class="choice_result_text">First<p>

                <div class="choice_result_width">
                </div>
                <span class="score">0%</span>

            </div>   


            <div class="choice_result" data-choice_percent="0">
                <p class="choice_result_text">Second<p>

                <div class="choice_result_width">
                </div>
                <span class="score">0%</span>

            </div>


            <div class="choice_result" data-choice_percent="100">
                <p class="choice_result_text">Third<p>

                <div class="choice_result_width">
                </div>
                <span class="score">100%</span>

            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

How would I do this?

Comment: are you populating this from api call?is it better to sort data there instead?

Comment: No this is static.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably what you're looking for:

```js
$('.poll_results.sort-by-score').each(function(){
  $(this).html(
    $(this).find('.choice_result').sort(function(a, b) {
      let dsa = parseInt($(a).find('.score').eq(0).text()),
          dsb = parseInt($(b).find('.score').eq(0).text());
      return (dsa > dsb ? -1 : (dsa < dsb) ? 1 : 0);
    })
  );  
});
```

```js
$('.poll_results.sort-by-score').each(function(){
  $(this).html(
    $(this).find('.choice_result').sort(function(a, b) {
      let dsa = parseInt($(a).find('.score').eq(0).text()),
          dsb = parseInt($(b).find('.score').eq(0).text());
      return (dsa > dsb ? -1 : (dsa < dsb) ? 1 : 0);
    })
  );  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="poll poll_answered">
  <div class="poll_div">
    <h1><strong>Percentages</strong></h1>
    <div class="poll_results sort-by-score" style="display: block;">

      <div class="choice_result" data-choice_percent="0">
        <p class="choice_result_text">First
        <p>
            <div class="choice_result_width"></div>
            <span class="score">0%</span>
      </div>


      <div class="choice_result" data-choice_percent="0">
        <p class="choice_result_text">Second
        <p>
            <div class="choice_result_width"></div>
            <span class="score">0%</span>

      </div>

      <div class="choice_result" data-choice_percent="100">
        <p class="choice_result_text">Third
        <p>

            <div class="choice_result_width"></div>
            <span class="score">100%</span>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="poll poll_answered">
  <div class="poll_div">
    <h1><strong>Not sorted percentages</strong></h1>
    <div class="poll_results" style="display: block;">

      <div class="choice_result" data-choice_percent="0">
        <p class="choice_result_text">First
        <p>
            <div class="choice_result_width"></div>
            <span class="score">0%</span>
      </div>


      <div class="choice_result" data-choice_percent="0">
        <p class="choice_result_text">Second
        <p>
            <div class="choice_result_width"></div>
            <span class="score">0%</span>

      </div>

      <div class="choice_result" data-choice_percent="100">
        <p class="choice_result_text">Third
        <p>

            <div class="choice_result_width"></div>
            <span class="score">100%</span>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It will reorder `.choice_result`s based on `text()` value from `.score` in each `.poll_results.sort-by-score` instances on your page.

**Important note:** This solution assumes `.choice_result` are the only children of `.poll_results`, as in your question.

Comment: Thanks this works, however are you able to adjust it if there are multiple `.poll_results` on a page? Because if I have 2 `.poll_results` on a page it will  sort every `.choice_result` into each `.poll_results`

Comment: You forgot to say what's the expected result. You only want this to happen in one of them? If yes, add `sort-by-score` class to those you want sorted and see the updated answer.

Comment: Yep the sorting works perfectly but it's now reversing the order of the multiple `.poll_results.`. Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: @Zorgan Can you please provide a fiddle? I'm not sure I understand the problem. It should only sort their contents, it should not sort themselves. Is it possible that this is done by some other attempt to sort the contents which you forgot to remove?

Comment: My mistake, I mean the multiple `.poll` are now in reversed order. So I have 2 `.poll` currently on my page, but after inserting your code they have been switched. Would anything in your code affect the sorting of the multiple `.poll`? And yeah it's probably on my end so nevermind.

Comment: No, the above code doesn't sort `.poll` at all. But in order to test, remove my code and see what happens. :)

Comment: Yeah you're right it doesn't affect `.poll`, i've sorted it out now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(".choice_result").sort(function(a, b) {
  a = parseFloat($(".score", a).text()); // get the value of .score element inside a
  b = parseFloat($(".score", b).text()); // get the value of .score element inside b
  return b - a;                          // sort descendently
}).appendTo(".poll_results");
```

```css
.choice_result {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="poll poll_answered">
  <div class="poll_div">
    <h1><strong>Percentages</strong></h1>
    <div class="poll_results" style="display: block;">
      <div class="choice_result" data-choice_percent="0">
        <p class="choice_result_text">First
          <p>
            <div class="choice_result_width">
            </div>
            <span class="score">30%</span>
      </div>
      <div class="choice_result" data-choice_percent="0">
        <p class="choice_result_text">Second
          <p>
            <div class="choice_result_width">
            </div>
            <span class="score">0%</span>
      </div>
      <div class="choice_result" data-choice_percent="100">
        <p class="choice_result_text">Third
          <p>
            <div class="choice_result_width">
            </div>
            <span class="score">100%</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Explanation:**

Get all the `.choice_result` elements (`$(".choice_result")`). Then sort using `.sort` function, for each two elements `a` and `b`, get the `.score` element of each (`$(".score", a or b)`) then get the text using `.text` function and parse the number before `%` using `parseFloat`, then return a negative number if `a` should be before `b`, a positive one otherwise (`b - a`). After sorting, reappend the elements back to their container (`appendTo(".poll_results")`).

Comment: fwiw, sharing suggestion of returning `-1`, `0`, or `1` from `.sort()` call

Comment: @guest271314 It doesn't have to be `-1` or `1` any negative or positive number will do. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?v=control

Comment: You are correct, appears result of `<` could be converted to `-1`, `1` "Let xSmaller be the result of performing Abstract Relational Comparison xString < yString.
If xSmaller is true, return -1.
Let ySmaller be the result of performing Abstract Relational Comparison yString < xString.
If ySmaller is true, return 1." https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.sort