# How can you sort the order of cards displayed in HTML?

Tags: python, html, django, sorting

I'm using Python and Django to build a website. I'm making a rough version of the homepage with Bootstrap and HTML. I have a group of Cards that have a time written on them (i.e "12:00AM" or "2:30PM"). How can I sort these cards in order of earliest to latest?

Below is my code. I put random data in there because I'm getting real data from Django.

```css
body {
  background: #272C31;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container py-2">
    <h1>Reservation Home</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card-group">
                <div class="card card text-white bg-dark" style="flex-grow:.39">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h2 class="card-title"> 3:00 </h2>
                        <h2 class="card-title"> PM </h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card text-white bg-dark ">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title"> Joe </h4>
                        <p class="card-text"> Member ID: abc </p>
                        <p class="card-text"> Number of Guests: 3</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-group">
                <div class="card card text-white bg-dark" style="flex-grow:.39">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h2 class="card-title"> 12:00 </h2>
                        <h2 class="card-title"> AM </h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card text-white bg-dark ">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title"> Jeff </h4>
                        <p class="card-text"> Member ID: xyz </p>
                        <p class="card-text"> Number of Guests: 2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

EDIT: views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Reservation
# Create your views here.
    
def home(request):
    context = {
        'reservations' : Reservation.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'reservation/reservation.html', context)
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.

class Reservation(models.Model):
    choices = (
        ('AM', 'AM'),
        ('PM', 'PM')
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    member_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="")
    guest_num = models.IntegerField()
    reserve_time = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    AM_PM = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices= choices,
        default= "PM",
    )


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} at {self.reserve_time}{self.AM_PM}"
```

Comment: You can check this question out and use JS to sort them on the page, if you aren't using Django to sort them beforehand https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43645828/sort-divs-based-on-values-of-child-elements

Comment: can you add the views.py

Comment: @AhmedKhairy I added views.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could to try in the views.py:

```
def home(request):
    context = {
        'reservations' : Reservation.objects.all().order_by('-reserve_time')
    }
    return render(request, 'reservation/reservation.html', context)
```

you should also to make it easier for you to choose the time in the models.py to:

```
reserve_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Comment: It looks like it sorted it from latest to earliest. Is there any way to make it so the earlier time shows up first?

Comment: @NicholasMamisashvili if you updated it to ``` order_by('reserve_time') ``` does it work ?

Comment: @NicholasMamisashvili check the updated answer you select the time that you want

Comment: It works, thank you! Is there a way for it to account if it is AM/PM?

Comment: Great! Thats why I suggest changing the model to a DateTimeField.